# How to get if android is in hands free mode?

Tags: android

I wan't to check if the user is operating the phone while a call is being made by using device's sensors and GPS.

I need to check if we are in hand free mode because in that case I should hear noise but may not see any movements or rotation.

I tried looking in android.telephony but found nothing. Also tried my good old friend google and no luck. Is it even doable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Your problem can be divided into 4 steps. Plus you dont need any sensors or GPS to achieve this.

1) Try to get connected Bluetooth Device list, via BluetoothAdapter class.

2) Check device class, via BluetoothDevice's APIs.

3) If you see Phone is connected to Bluetooth Device with capabilities like A2DP(audio) etc. Then you will know phone is in handsfree mode.

4) also try to find out phone_state of the phone. It shouln't be Idle, if you just want to check in state of making/receiving/during call.

Comment: Thanks. Got any idea how I could know if user is doing hands free call while no Bluetooth device is being used?

Comment: then, what is hands free. Why would user make call if he is not listening?

Comment: By hands free I mean the phone is on a table and everybody in the same room can listen to the conversation. I wan't to avoid false positives in my apps so I must support all normal use cases.

Comment: Do you mean, if the phones speaker is turned on? I think you should check for speaker state then. or can check gyro sensor to check phones angle!!